# How can I switch to tab view after open multiple files

Tags: vim

Sometimes, I will use `vim *.c` to open several files. after I open files, is there any way to switch tab view.
Currently, I only know to use `:qa` to exit vim, then open files `vim -p *.c` to show tab header. This looks a bit inefficient.

Is there any way that I can switch to tab view after I use vim open some files?

ps. I use vim 7.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another, slightly cleaner, way:

```
:tab ball
```

Each buffer is opened in its own window in its own tab page.

See `:help :tab` and `:help :ball`.

Comment: I think romainl answear is more good, as it will not open a empty tab.

Answer (score 4):

When you've passed all files to Vim on the command-line, these are in the *argument list*. You can therefore open all those files in separate tab pages via

```
:argdo tabedit
```

This will open an additional empty tab page, which you can just `:close`.